# VCDIFF for Java or alternative binary diff formats

Tags: java, compression, vcdiff

Is there an open-source Java implementation of the VCDIFF binary diff format (decoder and encoder)?

There are [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/) and [open-vcdiff](http://code.google.com/p/open-vcdiff/), but those are both C libraries.

Alternatively, are the other formats/algorithms that one could use to generate diffs for binary files from Java?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate binary diffs using badiff; the website is

http://badiff.org/

and it is available on maven central.  It's BSD licensed, so friendly for both OSS and commercial.  The algorithm used is a chunked version of the O(ND) diff described in this paper:

http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf

The diff format isn't particularly compatible with anything else, but it produces some really good and really small diffs.

The library is pretty fast; on my desktop machine it can generate a diff for two random 50MB input streams in 54 seconds.  Hopefully that's fast enough; I think it's reasonably impressive since that's a comparison of two token streams of 50 million tokens each.  badiff will take advantage of multiple CPU cores when computing diffs.

disclaimer: I'm the author of badiff, so of course I think it's cool.  I'm always open to suggestions; things like being able to read/write "standard" binary diff formats sound like cool new features to add in upcoming releases.

Comment: I've fixed some nasty bugs in the diff computation pipeline, so please use version 1.0.5 stable or higher.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Website broken? Can you please host it somewhere permanent like GitHub?

Answer (score 3):

I have a *decoder* for VCDIFF written in C#, which would probably be fairly straightforward to port to Java, if that's any help. It's part of [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) but I don't *think* it relies on any other bits of MiscUtil (or only minimally, anyway).

Unfortunately I never got round to writing an encoder, which is obviously rather harder - and wasn't necessary in our case (where we needed to apply patches in .NET on a mobile device, but could create them however we wanted at the server).

Comment: Actually, I am in a similar situation, so having just the decoder would probably work. I'll take a look at MiscUtil, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I hava ported MiscUtil's vcdiff decoder to java.
https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/jvcdiff
update: now it also have a vcdiff encoder

Comment: Did you take it down?

Comment: Some seems to have cloned the decoder here: https://github.com/keremkusmezer/jvcdiff

Answer (score 1):

There is a java-port of xdelta:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaxdelta/

But i can not say anything on its quality - i did not try it yet.

Comment: I think it does not do VCDIFF, but GDIFF, which is an older standard (and MUCH simpler). It does have both decoder and encoder, though.

Comment: javaxdelta works fine, we are using it for directory diffs (with [this wrapper](https://github.com/alexkasko/delta-updater)) in production

Answer (score 1):

I have a [Java port of open-vcdiff](https://github.com/ehrmann/vcdiff-java) on Github. It's tested against open-vcdiff, but it's not used in production anywhere.